# Weird DNS glitch windows

Tags: networking, google-chrome, dns

Whenever I load a website, I get this message. [image][image][image]

This applies to all websites which have not had their IP addresses cached.

I have flushed dns, reset winsock stuff, changed my dns servers to google public dns and back, and yet to no avail.

I have found that this issue can be temporarily fixed for about 5 minutes by going into **Network and sharing center > change adapter settings > right click on adapter > properties > IPv4 > Properties > OK > Close**

---

**EDIT**

Going into cmd and using the nslookup command works.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT I have used both a VPN and not a VPN, the problem persists. I am running Windows 10. I will try a different browser and review my network configuration shortly. I have not and do not intend to run an anti malware scan

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT I do not currently have access to the router. Have uploaded pics of other browsers. Do you have any idea why the solution at the bottom works? It certainly doesn't make sense.

Comment: How are you connected now to SU from a different PC, your phone, or what

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT I am using the temporary solution provided at the bottom of the page. Weird, but working. 'LSERVER' is not recognized as an internal or external command. My network adapter's IPv4 is 192.168.1.218

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43551/discussion-between-rubyjunk-and-pimp-juice-it).

Comment: "I have not and do not intend to run an anti malware scan" your issue sounds like malware behavior to me.

Comment: @Moab I simply don't want to install crap on my PC. I have not given any applications admin perms or installed anything in quite a while, so I doubt that a malicious program is causing the issue.